# How do I make custom automatically generated urls in html based off of stored data without more html files?

Tags: html, url

I'm making a website with html, css, and javascript. One of the features is creating an event. I've got the actual event display page working correctly, but I'm hoping to have the url for the page end with the name of the event. Eg. website.com/Events/BirthdayPartyFour or whatever the inputted name is. Ideally, people could type in this url and be sent to the page with the correct event. How would I go about doing this? Data is stored in another database, and so I just call the specific event's data when displaying that page.